# How to disable a mouse movement input, while leaving mouse buttons enabled?

Tags: x11, mouse

I have a mouse I just use for the buttons. I want to disable only the movement input of the mouse. Physically covering the sensor doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `xinput`.

```
>xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Mouse0                                id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Keyboard0
```

There you get the name of the mouse in this case Mouse0.

With the following command you slow down the speed of your mouse by a factor of 100000, which is then basically zero.

```
xinput --set-prop 6 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 100000
```

or

```
xinput --set-prop Mouse0 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 100000
```

To revert you can use the same

```
xinput --set-prop Mouse0 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1
```

Comment: Neat hack. The available properties can be found with `xinput list 6` (where `6` is the device). Documentation about the properties can be found here: http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/

Answer (score 3):

My mouse does not have 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' property.
I was still able to disable motion with

```
xinput set-prop 9 266 -1    
xinput set-prop 9 269 0 1
```

and reenable it with

```
xinput set-prop 9 269 1 0
input set-prop 9 266 0.0
```

I also disabled my buttons with

```
xinput set-button-map 9 0 0 0
```

Device 9 being my *Mitsumi Electric Apple Optical USB Mouse*.

**Device list**

```
Device 'Mitsumi Electric Apple Optical USB Mouse':
    Device Enabled (132):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (134): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (266):     -1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (267):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (268):        0, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (269):   0, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (270):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (271):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (272):       0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (250):     1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (251):        0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (252):        0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (273):     0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (274):     0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (275):        0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (276):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (277):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (278): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (279): 274
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (280):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (281):        0
    Device Node (253):      "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (254):        1452, 772
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (282):       <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (255):        1
```

Answer (score 2):

If I read `man 4 mousedrv` correctly, you could set, in the CorePointer section of your xorg.conf,

```
Option "EmulateWheel" true
Option "EmulateWheelButton" 0
Option "EmulateWheelInertia" 10000
```

which would convert movements into mouse wheel button events, but the inertia setting would make it too insensitive to ever register one. On modern systems, it is evdev instead of mousedrv. This can also be set at runtime using xinput, for example:

```
xinput --set-prop 17 'Evdev Wheel Emulation' 1
xinput --set-prop 17 'Evdev Wheel Emulation Button' 0
xinput --set-prop 17 'Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia' 10000
```

Where 17 should be your own device number. I use a function to get this number by the device name, and store it in $device-id during a startup script.

```
set_device_id() {
  device_id=$(xinput --list | grep -m 1 "$1")
  device_id=${device_id##*id=}
  device_id=${device_id%%[[:space:]]*}
}
```

This unfortunately has the side effect of disabling scroll wheel input of the device.